# The simplest curve which is never straight and has a rational arc length.

Tags: soft-question, rational-numbers, arc-length

[This](https://x.com/mayfer/status/1762014984660283717) tweet claims to give an explanation for why one should expect the perimeter of a circle with a rational radius to be irrational. It doesn't strike me as that convincing (although feel free to disagree).

A simple refutation would be to exhibit a smooth curve which is never straight, and yet has a rational arc length. Furthermore it needs to clearly not be smuggling any irrationality into its parameterization, so it should at least start and end at rational coordinates. (This second requirement is definitely a bit soft).

So, what's the simplest curve one can come up with which fits the criteria?

Comment: Consider $y=\frac{x^4+3}{6x}$ between any two positive rational values of $x$.

Comment: @Christian hmm yeah I'd prefer both be rational

Comment: Would you count something like the astroid, $x^{2/3} + y^{1/3} = 1$? It's a closed curve, and its cusps are at $(\pm 1, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1)$.

Comment: That was a bad temporary edit by my part. The example I gave should work.

Comment: You are probably missing more unstated assumptions, otherwise you can take a circle of radius $1/\pi$ passing through a rational point in the plane.

Comment: @MoisheKohan well it's definitely a vague statement, but setting the radius to an irrational number probably counts as "smuggling irrationality into its parameterization." I'm open to suggestions about how to formalize this.

Comment: @ChristianE.Ramirez Great! I think that'd be a good answer.

Comment: @Travis I think taking one quadrant of it would be fine, so that it's smooth except at the endpoints

Comment: I do not think there is a way to make a math question out of this.

Comment: @MoisheKohan One way to formalize it would still simply be to ask for a rational function which has a rational arc length between two rational points. I worry that's too restrictive though.

Comment: There's a typo in my earlier comment--the standard astroid has equation $x^{2/3}+y^{\color{red}{2/3}} = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple family of curves such that the arc length over any interval $[a, b]$ with rational endpoints (and, say, $0 < a < b$) is rational.

Fix $n \in \{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$ and $c \in \Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ and define
$$f(x) = c x^{n + 1} + \frac{1}{4 (n^2 - 1) c x^{n - 1}} .$$
In particular, the endpoints $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ are rational. The arc length element for the graph of $f$ is
$$ds = \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2} \,dx = \left((n + 1) c x^n + \frac{1}{4 (n + 1) c x^n}\right) dx,$$
and so the arc length of $f$ over $[a, b]$ is
$$\int ds = \left. c x^{n + 1} - \frac{1}{4 (n^2 - 1) c x^{n - 1}}\right\vert_a^b = c (b^{n + 1} - a^{n + 1}) - \frac{1}{4(n^2 - 1)c}\left(\frac{1}{b^{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a^{n + 1}}\right),$$
which in particular is rational.